# Matlab multiply each row in matrix by different number

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, multiplication

Say that I have a matrix:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9 ; 10 11 12];
```

Is there a way to multiply :
row 1 by 1
row 2 by 2
row 3 by 3
and so on?

I am able to do this with for loops, however it if for an assignment where they want us to use matrices.
In the actual assignment `A` is filled with random number but each row which by multiplied consecutively.

Thanks, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have a look at the `bsxfun` function - it does exactly what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to multiply a diagonal matrix by A like so.

```
A = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9 ; 10 11 12];
disp(diag([1 2 3 4]) * A);

 1     2     3
 8    10    12
21    24    27
40    44    48
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `bsxfun` to accomplish this easily and very quickly

```
out = bsxfun(@times, [1 2 3 4].', A)
```

In newer versions of MATLAB (R2016b and newer) you can actually replace `bsxfun` with simply `*`

```
out = [1 2 3 4].' * A;
```

Comment: gosh, that `.'` was what I was looking for over hours!
Thanks.